# Mule Database endpoint JDBC test connection

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have created a database endpoint. But while testing the connection I am getting the following error:

```
Test connection failed: Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201305131832/mule/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/security/oauth/processor/AbstractExpressionEvaluator (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
org.mule.common.MuleArtifactFactoryException: Error initializing
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationMuleArtifactFactory.doGetArtifact(SpringXmlConfigurationMuleArtifactFactory.java:149)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationMuleArtifactFactory.getArtifact(SpringXmlConfigurationMuleArtifactFactory.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationMuleArtifactFactory.getArtifact(SpringXmlConfigurationMuleArtifactFactory.java:39)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:72)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:108)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:72)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a Cloud Connector for Mule 3.5 in your project?

If yes, it's a well-known issue: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-3831